# Subscribe to controller viewWillAppear event?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, lifecycle

I would like to register code to a controller's `viewWillAppear` event so it can be triggered at a later time when that event fires. Is this possible?

For example, below I would like to register code for deep linking to trigger code later, otherwise my code runs too early before `viewWillAppear`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  if let storyboard = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.storyboard,
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mycontroller") as? MyControllerController {
    controller.loadData() // TOO EARLY, how to execute this in the viewWillAppear event?
  }
}
```

Comment: Not following. Why don't you just call loadData in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Because if I do in the application/openUrl event, it's too early in my app and the IBOutlets are nil.